# how to assign values in array key and value pair one array to another array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, join, array-splice

```
var a = ['lkg','ukg'];
var b = ['lkg_stud_name','ukg_stud_name'];
```

I want to below like this?

```
 var c =(
        ['lkg','lkg_stud_name'],
        ['ukg','ukg_stud_name']
    );
```

For example `a[0]` and `b[0]` in same row, `a[1]` and `b[1]` in same row in array `c`.

Please help me

Comment: What is `c` supposed to be? It’s just `['ukg','ukg_stud_name']`, currently.

Comment: @lealceldeiro It _is_ valid, but certainly not what the OP wants.

Comment: Did you mean the outer parentheses to be square brackets?

Comment: The description suggests the result should be `var c =[
        ['lkg','lkg_stud_name'],
        ['ukg','ukg_stud_name']
    ];`

Answer (score 2):

You can do that fairly easily by [`mapping`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)through the values of one array assuming they are both the same length:

```js
var a = ['lkg','ukg'];
var b = ['lkg_stud_name','ukg_stud_name'];

var c = a.map((item, index) => [item, b[index]])
console.log(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is using the function `Array.from`.

This is assuming both arrays have the same length.

```js
var a = ['lkg','ukg'],
    b = ['lkg_stud_name','ukg_stud_name'],
    c = Array.from({length: a.length}, (_, i) => [a[i], b[i]]);

console.log(c);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Wider compatible approach using `for-loop`:**

```js
var a = ['lkg','ukg'],
    b = ['lkg_stud_name','ukg_stud_name'],
    c = [];
    
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) c.push([a[i], b[i]]);

console.log(c);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```